# Pie Chart not showing expected output

Tags: java, swing, pie-chart, java-2d, angle

I'm trying to keep my piechart up to date to the data that changes during the simulator run.

My issue is that the piechart is not showing the data the correct way and I've no clue what the issue is.

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 

        int totalAmountOfCars = this.adhocCars + this.reservationCars + this.parkpassCars;
        float percentageAdHoc = totalAmountOfCars <= 0 || this.adhocCars <= 0 ? 0 : adhocCars/totalAmountOfCars * 100;
        float percentageParkPass = totalAmountOfCars <= 0 || this.parkpassCars <= 0 ? 0 :parkpassCars/totalAmountOfCars * 100;
        float percentageReservation = totalAmountOfCars <= 0 || this.reservationCars <= 0 ? 0 :reservationCars/totalAmountOfCars * 100;


        float adHocAngle = totalAmountOfCars <= 0 || this.adhocCars <= 0 ? 0 : 360/percentageAdHoc*100;
        float parkPassAngle = totalAmountOfCars <= 0 || this.parkpassCars <= 0 ? 0 : 360/percentageParkPass*100;
        float reservationAngle = totalAmountOfCars <= 0 || this.reservationCars <= 0 ? 0 : 360/percentageReservation*100;

        Dimension prefSize = this.getPreferredSize();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(prefSize.width/2, prefSize.height/2, 200, 200);
```

Here I calculate the angles for the arcs..

```
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillArc(prefSize.width/2 + 10, prefSize.height/2 + 10, 180, 180, 0,(int)adHocAngle);
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.fillArc(prefSize.width/2 + 10, prefSize.height/2 + 10, 180, 180, (int)adHocAngle, (int)adHocAngle+(int)parkPassAngle);
g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
g.fillArc(prefSize.width/2 + 10, prefSize.height/2 + 10, 180, 180,(int)adHocAngle+(int)parkPassAngle, (int)reservationAngle);
```

This part should fill it, in some cases the entire chars is filled orange and in other cases its for 99% red with a tiny line of blue. Instead of 30%,40%,30% for example.

Yellow Chart:
[image]

Red/Blue Chart:
[image]

Comment: It's hard for most of us to guess what could be wrong since we are unable to test small isolated bits of code. We don't want to see a whole large program as that would overwhelm us with code, most of it completely unrelated to your problem, but we do greatly appreciate it when a poster puts in the little effort to create a small compilable and runnable demonstration program, an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at the link for more details on just what we're asking you to post.

Comment: Also this: `" My issue is that the piechart is not showing the data the correct way..."` -- tells us little of use. How *exactly* is your program misbehaving? The details do matter.

Comment: `360/percentageAdHoc*100;` That `360` looks very suspicious. Java trigonometric methods typically work in radians.

Comment: Suggestion 1: If you still need our help, again consider creating and posting that [mcve] -- up to you if you wish to do this or not, but again it will make helping you **much** easier. Suggestion 2: Most of that code should be outside of paintComponent and inside of separate **and easily testable** methods. This can make your debugging easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be how you're calling `Graphics#fillArc(...)`. If you look at the [Graphics API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html), and in particular at this method, you'll see:

> ```
> public abstract void fillArc(int x,  
>                              int y,
>                              int width,
>                              int height,
>                              int startAngle,
>                              int arcAngle)
> ```

Note that the description of the last parameter, arcAngle, states:

> arcAngle - the angular extent of the arc, relative to the start angle.

You may be calling the method as if it represented the final degree angle of the arc, but that's not how it should be called. Again it should represent the **extent** of the arc in degrees.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PieDemo extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final Color BG = Color.WHITE;
    private static final int GAP = 40;
    public static final int TIMER_DELAY = 400;
    private int redPercent = 0;
    private int bluePercent = 0;
    // green will be remainder

    public PieDemo() {
        setBackground(BG);
        add(new JButton(new StartDemoAction("Start", KeyEvent.VK_S)));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int redAngle = (redPercent * 360) / 100;
        int blueAngle = (bluePercent * 360) / 100;
        int greenAngle = 360 - redAngle - blueAngle;
        greenAngle = Math.max(greenAngle, 0);
        int startAngle = 0;
        startAngle = drawPie(g, Color.green, startAngle, greenAngle);
        startAngle = drawPie(g, Color.RED, startAngle, redAngle);
        startAngle = drawPie(g, Color.BLUE, startAngle, blueAngle);
    }

    private int drawPie(Graphics g, Color color, int startAngle, int arcAngle) {
        int x = GAP;
        int y = GAP;
        int w = getWidth() - 2 * GAP;
        int h = getHeight() - 2 * GAP;
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillArc(x, y, w, h, startAngle, arcAngle);
        return startAngle + arcAngle;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class StartDemoAction extends AbstractAction {
        private Timer timer = null;
        public StartDemoAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
                return;
            }
            redPercent = 0;
            bluePercent = 0;
            repaint();
            timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        private static final int BOUND = 10;
        private Random random = new Random();

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (redPercent + bluePercent >= 100) {
                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            } else {
                redPercent += random.nextInt(BOUND);
                bluePercent += random.nextInt(BOUND / 2);

                if (redPercent + bluePercent > 100) {
                    bluePercent = 100 - redPercent;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        PieDemo mainPanel = new PieDemo();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PieDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to make sure your calculations for percentages are correct first.

```
adhocCars/totalAmountOfCars * 100;
```

Should be

```
100/totalAmountOfCars * adhocCars;
```